# JCL requires source in Delphi library path

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, jedi, jedi-code-library

I've installed the JCL into Rad-Studo XE2 and chose the option to modify the library paths as appropriate. This added z:\3rd party\Jedi 3.45\jcl\lib\d16\win32, and z:\3rd party\Jedi 3.45\jcl\source\include to the library path in my environment. The win32 directory contains all of the dcu, obj, lib, dcp and res files, freshly compiled, just like it should.

The problem is that if I use a jcl file in my code I am unable to build it unless I add all of the jcl*.pas files to the path. Once I've done that code completion goes for poo, as it seems to be continually recompiling everything.

Where have I gone wrong?

[image: Library path screenshot]

Comment: Did you install JCL using it's own installer or manually?

Comment: .dcu files should suffice for compilation. In case you have 'use debug dcus', also check the 'debug dcu path' in directory options - it should include '..\win32\debug\'.

Comment: By 'use a JCL file in my code' you mean adding the .pas files in your USES directive?

Comment: @LightBulb, I used the Jedi installer. Since then I've also installed everything from the JVCL but there are NO jedi components in the Tool Palette.  I have some TMS and Mitov components installed though, and they show up properly. There must be something wrong with my installation.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic, Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: @Sertac, that is certainly what I've always understood, but something is clearly up!

Comment: @marcp Try moving JCL items in the Library Path somewhere closer to the top of the list, preferably before other 3rd party components. I remember solving similar problem just by reordering the list.

Comment: Which edition of Delphi? Starter?

Comment: @lightbulb - nope, that didn't work

Comment: @David - its professional with C Builder and Delphi. I've been using it for about 6 months but just installed the jedi components because I need to recompile some old code...

Comment: More information: The Z drive above is a network drive, so I've moved it all to C: but that didn't work. While reinstalling JVCL from C I did notice a warning that the bpl directory wasn't on my path, so after fixing that I at least have the JVCL components working now. I also added the directory containing the dcus to my system path, to no effect.